# Elementary Set theory proof: $A \subseteq B$ iff $A \cap B=A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove:

$A \subseteq B$ iff $A \cap B=A$

Can someone give me a hint on how to start this? I know in order to prove two sets are equal you have to take an arbitrary item from one set and show it is in the other and then vice versa but how do I apply it to this case?

Comment: Just edited your post. What you said was "A union B" but that "union" symbol turned sideways denotes a subset. You want to say "A is a subset of B". Also, try starting with "Let $x \in A$".

Comment: my question given in my textbook is A union B though..

Comment: $A \cup B$ by itself doesn't really mean anything in the context of this proof. Was it $A \cup B =B$?

Comment: it was a long proof where A⊆B iff A∪B iff  A∩B=A iff not B⊆A

Comment: Perhaps $A\cup B=B\Leftrightarrow A\cap B= A$?

Comment: I got step 1 to 2 and step 3 to 4 I just need help getting from 2 to 3 if that makes sense?

Comment: @Jem I don't know what that has to do with anything. But at any rate, you can leave the proof statement as edited above, or change it to what Lehs has suggested. Both are equivalent statements here. What is step 2?

Comment: @Jem, **what** steps 1,2,3,4??

Answer (score 2):

Ideas:

Suppose $\;A\subset B\implies \forall\,a\in A\;,\;\;\text{also}\;\;a\in B\;$ . Now, prove that $\;A\cap B=A\;$ taking into account that it is **always** true that $\;A\cap B\subset \begin{cases}A\\\text{and also}\\B\end{cases}\;$

The other direction is easier taking into account the last relation in the above line.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is divided in two parts:

1. "If": let's demonstrate $A \subseteq B \Longrightarrow A \cap B = A$:

Let $A$, $B$ be sets such than $A \subseteq B$. This means that the implication $x \in A \Longrightarrow x \in B$ will be always true.

Now, the intersection $A \cap B$ can be written as:

$$A \cap B = \left\{ x \ \vert \ x \in A \land x \in B \right\}$$

But just because $x \in A$ implies automatically (well, by the hypotheses) that $x \in B$, its sufficient to write:

$$A \cap B = \left\{ x \ \vert \ x \in A \right\}$$

Recall that the above set is $A$. This demonstrates true that $A \subseteq B \Longrightarrow A \cap B = A$.

2. "Only if": let's demonstrate $A \cap B = A \Longrightarrow A \subseteq B$:

Let $A$, $B$ be sets such than $A \cap B = A$. This implies that the expressions $x \in A \cap B$ and $x \in A$ are logically equivalent. Now take an arbitray element $a \in A$. That would imply that $a \in A \cap B$. Therefore, every element in $A$ is also in $A \cap B$. But because every element in $A \cap B$ is also element of $B$, then every element of $A$ is also in $B$, and that is written as $A \subseteq B$. This demonstrates that $A \cap B = A \Longrightarrow A \subseteq B$.

Therefore, $$A \subseteq B \Longleftrightarrow A \cap B = A$$

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Assume $A\subset B$. Show that that $A\cap B =A$.

- **Step 1a:** Show that $A\cap B \subset A$.
- **Step 1b:** Show that $A \subset A \cap B$. (Hint: Use $A\subset B$)

**Step 2:** Assume $A\cap B =A$. Prove that $A\subset B$. (Hint: Similar to step 1a).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion regarding the "$\cup$" symbol. Saying "$A\cup B$ iff $ A\cap B=A$" doesn't make sense. It's like saying "show $x+y$ iff $x - y = 2$."   But now what is $x+y$? Without knowing what $x+y$ is equal to we don't have anywhere to start. Similarly, you need to know what $A \cup B$ is equal to. From what I can gather from this problem, I feel strongly that $A\cup B =B$ is the assumption you need to make. That being said, here is how you could do the forward direction of the proof.

($\implies$) Suppose that $A \cup B = B$ (or equivalently $A \subset B$). We know that $A \cap B \subset A$ because every element of $A\cap B$ is an element of $A$. Now let $x \in A$. Then we also know $x \in B$ since $A \subset B$. Now that we know $x \in A$ and $x\in B$ we know $x \in A\cap B$. This means $A \subset A\cap B$. However, we have now shown that $$A \cap B \subset A \quad \text{and}\quad  A \subset A\cap B$$ so by double containment we have $A = A\cap B$.

$(\impliedby)$ Now for the other direction, assume $A \cap B = A$. You should be able to use a similar process as outlined in the above paragraph to arrive at the conclusion that $A \subset B$. I will leave it to you.